# Reducing json data to a form that avoids the duplicate values within a specific json key

Tags: java, json

Can any one please suggest me a way to reduce a given json to a simpler one based on the duplicate values present in it . For eg : if following is my json data ,

```
{
    "result": [{
        "LOCATION": [
            "US",
            "United States",
            "United States",
            "Honolulu",
            "Hawaii",
            "Chicago",
            "13th District",
            "United States"
        ],
        "ORGANIZATION": [
            "Columbia University",
            "Harvard Law School",
            "Harvard Law School",
            "University of Chicago Law School",
            "Illinois Senate",
            "House of Representatives"
        ]
    }]
}

Then i need the output after json reduction as ,

{
    "result": [{
        "LOCATION": [
            "US",
            "United States (3)",
            "Honolulu",
            "Hawaii",
            "Chicago",
            "13th District"
        ],
        "ORGANIZATION": [
            "Columbia University",
            "Harvard Law School (2)",
            "University of Chicago Law School",
            "Illinois Senate",
            "House of Representatives"
        ]
    }]
}
```

i.e Each duplicate value must be replaced by a single same value and the count of occurrences of the same in the json. Is there any library available to do this as such ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use `set` while parsing to store data

Comment: How are you processing your json? Show us more details (code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post your code and give your requirements more clearly. Whether there is some POJO available for this JSON?
Directly no library can go inside the arrays and change it as per your requirement so you have to write your own custom parser.

I created a sample code snippet by assuming three things:

Your structure will remain same i.e :

1. An outside element "result" which is an array
2. Each Array Elements itself is one more object
3. Inside that object we have many arrays which you need to optimize

EXAMPLE:

```
{
    "result": [//ASSUMPTION [1]

    {                                               //ASSUMPTION [2]
        "LOCATION": [                               //ASSUMPTION [3]
            "US",
            "United States",
            "United States",
            "Honolulu",
            "Hawaii",
            "Chicago",
            "13th District",
            "United States"
        ],
        "ORGANIZATION": [                           //ASSUMPTION [3]
            "Columbia University",
            "Harvard Law School",
            "Harvard Law School",
            "University of Chicago Law School",
            "Illinois Senate",
            "House of Representatives"
        ]
    },
    {                                               //ASSUMPTION [2]
        "LOCATION": [                               //ASSUMPTION [3]
            "United States",
            "United States"
        ],
        "ORGANIZATION": [                           //ASSUMPTION [3]
            "Harvard Law School",
            "Harvard Law School"
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

After passing it to code, I got this result:

```
[{
    "LOCATION": ["US", "Honolulu", "Hawaii", "Chicago", "13th District", "United States (3)"],
    "ORGANIZATION": ["Columbia University", "University of Chicago Law School", "Illinois Senate", "House of Representatives", "Harvard Law School (2)"]
}, {
    "LOCATION": ["United States (2)"],
    "ORGANIZATION": ["Harvard Law School (2)"]
}]
```

It's very raw code without any optimization but you will get the idea.

CODE SNIPPET:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        // convert JSON string to Map
        map = mapper.readValue(new File("c://drive//test.json"), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
        });
        System.out.println("map " + map);

        // Value of result element i.e array
        List<Map<String, Object>> result = (List<Map<String, Object>>) map.get("result");
        System.out.println("result " + result);
        // Traverse over array, Each element inside is one more object (ASSUMPTION 2)
        for (Map<String, Object> resultMap : result) {
            List<String> traversed = new ArrayList<>();
            // Traverse over each object
            for (Entry<String, Object> entry : resultMap.entrySet()) {
                // Each object contains a list
                List<String> insideMostArray = (List<String>) entry.getValue();
                // Entries to remove
                Map<String, Integer> removedEntry = new HashMap<>();
                // Inside most values
                for (String insideMostArrayTemp : insideMostArray) {
                    if (traversed.contains(insideMostArrayTemp)) {
                        removedEntry.put(insideMostArrayTemp, removedEntry.get(insideMostArrayTemp) == null ? 2
                                : (removedEntry.get(insideMostArrayTemp) + 1));
                    } else {
                        traversed.add(insideMostArrayTemp);
                    }
                }
                //Remove all duplicate entries and replace with 1 entry
                for (Entry<String, Integer> entriesToRemove : removedEntry.entrySet()) {
                    insideMostArray.removeAll(Collections.singleton(entriesToRemove.getKey()));
                    insideMostArray.add(entriesToRemove.getKey() + " (" + entriesToRemove.getValue() + ")");
                }
            }
        }
        String optimizedJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(result);
    }
```